# Set application memory size from PySpark shell

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am trying to sort 25 million integers. But when I am trying to use `collect()`, it is giving me a `OutofMemory Error: Java Heap Space` error. Below is the source code:

```
sc = SparkContext("local", "pyspark")
numbers = sc.textFile("path of text file")
counts = numbers.flatMap(lambda x: x.split()).map(lambda x: (int(x), 1)).sortByKey(lambda x:x)
num_list = []
for (num, count) in counts.collect():
    num_list.append(num)
```

Where am I going wrong? The size of text file is 147MB. All the settings are default. I am using Spark v0.9.0.

Edit: Works file with 2.5 million integers. But problem starts with 5 million. Also tested with 10 millions and got same OME error.

Here is the stack trace:

```
14/02/06 22:44:31 ERROR Executor: Exception in task ID 5
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2798)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:111)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1870)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1779)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1186)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Executor.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
14/02/06 22:44:31 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost TID 5 (task 0.0:0)
14/02/06 22:44:31 WARN TaskSetManager: Loss was due to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2798)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:111)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1870)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1779)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1186)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Executor.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
14/02/06 22:44:31 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0.0:0 failed 1 times; aborting job
14/02/06 22:44:31 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Remove TaskSet 0.0 from pool 
14/02/06 22:44:31 INFO DAGScheduler: Failed to run collect at <ipython-input-7-cf9439751c70>:1
```